# MySql REGEXP operator

Tags: mysql, regex, operators

The mySql REGEXP operator is not case sensitive. Is there a version of this operator that **is** case sensitive?

Comment: that is what documentation says but if you take a look bit further i.e. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp the example `As a more complex example, the regular expression B[an]*s matches any of the strings Bananas, Baaaaas, Bs, and any other string starting with a B, ending with an s, and containing any number of a or n characters in between.`

Comment: I think this depends on your storage engine, InnoDB, MyISAM etc. Have you tried it on different types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `BINARY` keyword, which forces `REGEXP` to match the string as a binary string, which is done case-sensitively.

```
SELECT 'a' REGEXP 'A', 'a' REGEXP BINARY 'A';
```

Although this isn't explicitly [stated in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) (that you can do it with a regular string), in my experience it works as expected.